# Oracle SQL: Pivot on multiple columns/fields

Tags: sql, oracle, microsoft-query

I want to create a table where the entries of various columns are 'pivoted' to column headers. The table is for reporting purposes - my users want to query data via Excel (using Microsoft Query), and the problem is that doing the pivoting in Excel makes the files unpractically large and slow even for moderately-sized data sets (~100k data points).

Consider the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE tt
(   
  "COMMODITY" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
  "MARKET"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
  "BID_ASK"   VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
  "PRICE"     NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO tt VALUES ('Gold','US','Ask',1.1);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES ('Gold','US','Bid',1);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES ('Gold','EU','Ask',1.2);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES ('Gold','EU','Bid',1.1);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES ('Oil','US','Ask',11);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES ('Oil','US','Bid',10);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES ('Oil','EU','Ask',12);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES ('Oil','EU','Bid',11);
```

The output that I want to achieve would be something like (the exact column headers don't matter much):

```
COMMODITY   'US_Bid'    'US_Ask'    'EU_Bid'    'EU_Ask'
Gold         1           1.1         1.1        1.2
Oil          10          11          11         12
```

Now it is straightforward to pivot a single column:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM tt
)
PIVOT
(
  SUM(PRICE)
  FOR MARKET IN ('US','EU')
)
```

Which gives:

```
COMMODITY   BID_ASK 'US'    'EU'
Gold        Bid      1      1.1
Oil         Bid      10     11
Oil         Ask      11     12
Gold        Ask      1.1    1.2
```

According to my research there is no syntax for directly pivoting multiple columns. There are some related questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590799/tsql-pivot-multiple-columns), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662012/sql-server-pivot-on-multiple-columns) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058912/sql-pivot-on-three-colums)), but I could not find a direct answer to my problem there. So I came up with the following solution:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT COMMODITY, CONCAT(CONCAT(MARKET,'_'),BID_ASK) AS MARKET_BID_ASK, PRICE FROM tt
)
PIVOT
(
  SUM(PRICE)
  FOR MARKET_BID_ASK IN ('US_Bid','US_Ask','EU_Bid','EU_Ask')
)
```

This produces exactly the desired output. However, I do not consider it a practical solution as the number of variables that I have to enter grows way too fast (in my real data set, I want to pivot more fields at once, all of which have many different values). I know that there exist [dynamic pivots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query), however I am not sure whether this will work with Excel, and I would also like to keep the syntax as simple as possible, because the users will define queries on their own (I just want to provide a template query that they can adapt). So I tried to query the field names in the IN-clause:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT COMMODITY, CONCAT(CONCAT(MARKET,'_'),BID_ASK) AS MARKET_BID_ASK, PRICE FROM tt
)
PIVOT
(
  SUM(PRICE)
  FOR MARKET_BID_ASK IN 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(CONCAT(MARKET,'_'),BID_ASK) AS MARKET_BID_ASK FROM tt
  )
)
```

I think that such a solution could be practical, because one could still constrain the variables queried without having to list all the concatenated options using LIKE-conditions in the subquery. However, I get an "ORA-00936 - missing expression" error with this query, even though subqueries should be legal here according to the [documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php) that I found.

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651147/how-to-transpose-column-into-row-in-oracle-sql-11g/38653133#38653133 and try with **select * from table(pivot(Q'$ SELECT COMMODITY, CONCAT(CONCAT(MARKET,'_'),BID_ASK) AS MARKET_BID_ASK, PRICE FROM tt $'))**

Comment: Dynamic Sql is exactly the way to go when you need to pivot  fields which are defined by user at runtime. Create a VBA function which will build Sql command text according to user choice.

Comment: I think the "documentation" you found is incorrect. If you consult the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE) you see that the subquery option is only allowed in conjunction with the XML keyword.

Comment: just fyi for everyone, after some experience I can tell that the Excel-based workaround that I tried (doing one query per column) is not very practical either. I suppose dynamic SQL is indeed the only solution. If I can find the time to get this working in a practical way I'll post the solution here...

Answer (score 14):

You can pivot on multiple columns by enclosing the columns, and the sets of values, in parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM tt
)
PIVOT
(
  SUM(PRICE)
  FOR (MARKET, BID_ASK)
  IN (('US', 'Bid') us_bid, ('US', 'Ask') us_ask, ('EU', 'Bid') eu_bid, ('EU', 'Ask') eu_ask)
);

COMMODITY      US_BID     US_ASK     EU_BID     EU_ASK
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Gold                1        1.1        1.1        1.2
Oil                10         11         11         12
```

but the value pairs still have to be known when the query is parsed, and this doesn't scale well if you have a lot of combinations of values.

Your only alternative is dynamic SQL, as you suspected, unless you can get Excel to process the result of an XML pivot - which I don't think is possible. With dynamic SQL you could perhaps have a function that does the query and pivot and returns a ref cursor, if Excel finds that easier to handle than the pivot query.